# HTML Help Control and parent application crashes when try to open pdf file linked in CHM

Tags: pdf, chm

I have a CHM file which have link to PDF in Table Of Content.
I try to open this CHM from my .NET Application using `Help.ShowHelp()` method.

When the CHM is opened in HTML Help Viewer, and I try to open pdf link from TOC, the HTML Help control crashes along with parent application.

Following are the specifications of system and the application:

```
OS: Server 2012
.NET Version: 4.0
IE: 11.0
Acrobat Reader DC: 15.0
```

After crash when looked into event viewer found following error:

```
Faulting application name: ABC.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x57061199
Faulting module name: AcroPDFImpl64.dll_unloaded, version: 15.10.20056.36345, time stamp: 0x567400fc
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000046c6c
Faulting process id: 0x6b9c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d19560fb9af8f4
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\XYZ\PPP\MM\ABC.exe
Faulting module path: AcroPDFImpl64.dll
Report Id: 78e86abc-0154-11e6-8100-000c29d549d9
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Please provide any pointers to how can I overcome the crash.

Thanks,
PJ

Comment: Please provide some Information by editing your question about where your PDF is stored. Embedded (means compiled into CHM), not embedded (means installed but outside of the CHM) or downloaded from server by URL. We also have no information yet whether you are the help author with all right to compile a new CHM or not. Please note that my example link posted in the answer includes a special way opening a PDF from a HTML topic file. This is decribed in the sample  topic themself. 
Please post your programming language and your `ShowHelp` call code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this from scratch and I can't reproduce your error on my Windows10 machine with Visual Basic 2015, HTMLHelp Workshop and FAR HTML installed. It's working for me (see snap below).

What I see is, you are in server environment - I'm not. You may know there are security problems when downloading CHM from a server.

My Table of Contents (TOC) is build with following *.hhc snippet. The third link to a PDF (not embedded) I tried later (not in the snap) but this is working too.

```
  <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Name" value="PDF Link from TOC">
      </OBJECT>
  <UL>
     <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
           <param name="Name" value="PDF - Example Help-Info.de">
           <param name="Local" value="pdf/help-info.pdf">
         </OBJECT>
     <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
           <param name="Name" value="PDF - Example GDI-NI">
           <param name="Local" value="pdf/gdi-ni.pdf">
         </OBJECT>
     <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
           <param name="Name" value="Link to PDF (NOT embedded - server)">
           <param name="Local" value="http://www.help-info.de/files_download/pdf/example-server.pdf">
           <param name="ImageNumber" value="11">
         </OBJECT>
```

The first and second link go to embedded PDF's means the PDF's are compiled into the CHM. This is done by some additional commands in the CHM's project file:

```
[FILES]
svg\*.svg
pdf\*.pdf
```

If you are not the help author of your CHM it's a major question how PDF's are compiled or linked in your case. Please check if your CHM is working by double click as stand-alone file.

For some additional test you may download a CHM sample from my site at:

[Project with all files and tricky examples](http://www.help-info.de/files_download/CHM-example_project.zip)

Extract the CHM file and test in your application. Please note you have to unblock the CHM file when coming from the internet.

The CHM file has PDF samples for cases when the PDF content must be updated by patch installer. PDF is not compiled into the CHM but installed in this case.

[image]

Comment: Hi @help-info.de Thanks for you reply. I also tried the same with sample but was not able to reproduce it but it is consistently reproducible in my application. It would be good if could point me to what all could be probable suspects in application which might be causing this issue.

Comment: Difficult - please remember HTMLHelp is about 20 years old and a PDF linking from Table of Contents (TOC) is - AFAIK - not a feature. I'll try to follow up with some thoughts after you edit and give some more Information (see comment above).

Comment: I am getting following error: There is a problem with Adobe Acrobat/Reader.
If it is running, please exit and try again. (103:103)
The Acrobat reader I have on server 2012 is Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. When searched for this error got to turn off protected mode on startup which is already done and still facing the issue.